# Sort list of dictionaries based on values where keys have different names

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which look like the following:

```
my_list = [
          {'1200' : [10, 'A']},
          {'1000' : [24, 'C']},
          {'9564' : [6, 'D']},
          ]
```

All dictionaries in the list have one key-value pair.

I want to sort it based on the first element of each dictionaries value which is a list, so the sorted list would look like:

```
my_list_sorted = [
          {'9564' : [6, 'D']},
          {'1200' : [10, 'A']},
          {'1000' : [24, 'C']},
          ]
```

As you can see the keys have different names and that's why I could not use answers from, for example, the following post: [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Do all your dicts only have one key-value pair?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of that question because as OP said, the keys are different.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, The situation looks different, although it's asking the same question. There's no keys in common.

Comment: @schwobaseggl This is completely a different question as I have described it in the text. I updated the title as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `values()` to access the `dict` elements:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x.values()[0][0])
```

Output:

```
[
  {'9564': [6, 'D']},
  {'1200': [10, 'A']},
  {'1000': [24, 'C']}
]
```

This assumes that each entry contains a list with at least one element.

**EDIT FOR PYTHON 3**

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ points out, `values()` does not return a list in python3, so you'll have to do:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: list(x.values()[0])[0])
```

Comment: `x.values()[0]` gives you the whole list, they just want to sort by the first element.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Premature cut and paste- thanks for pointing that out. It's fixed now.

Comment: Also, beware that `x.values()[0][0]` does not work on python3, since `.values()` doesn't return a list there.

Answer (score 5):

```
sorted(my_list,key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0][0])
Out[114]: [{'9564': [6, 'D']}, {'1200': [10, 'A']}, {'1000': [24, 'C']}]
```